# Get element names and values from a section of an iXML object

Tags: xml, abap

I am trying to get tag `Totales` and its children from this XML :

```
<Body>
  <Receptor>
    <RUTRecep>9655</RUTRecep>
  </Receptor>
  <Totales>
    <MntNeto>63934</MntNeto>
    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>
    <MntTotal>76081</MntTotal>
  </Totales>
</Body>
```

My code returns ONLY the values of the tags, not the tag names:

> Totales
>
> 639341976081

I want both names and values, inside `Totales`:

> MntNeto
>
> 63934
>
> TasaIVA
>
> 19
>
> MntTotal
>
> 76081

This is my code :

```
DATA(lo_ixml) = cl_ixml=>create( ).
DATA(lo_stream_factory) = lo_ixml->create_stream_factory( ).
DATA(lo_doc) = lo_ixml->create_document( ).

IF lo_ixml->create_parser(
          document       = lo_doc
          stream_factory = lo_stream_factory
          istream        = lo_stream_factory->create_istream_string( string =
                `<Body>                                      ` &&
                `  <Receptor>                                ` &&
                `    <RUTRecep>9655</RUTRecep>               ` &&
                `  </Receptor>                               ` &&
                `  <Totales>                                 ` &&
                `    <MntNeto>63934</MntNeto>                ` &&
                `    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>                   ` &&
                `    <MntTotal>76081</MntTotal>              ` &&
                `  </Totales>                                ` &&
                `</Body>                                     ` )
      )->parse( ) <> 0.
  RETURN.
ENDIF.

DATA(lo_node_col) = lo_doc->get_elements_by_tag_name( name = 'Totales' ).
DATA(lo_iterator) = lo_node_col->create_iterator( ).
DATA(lo_node) = lo_iterator->get_next( ).

WHILE NOT lo_node IS INITIAL.
  DATA(lf_name)  = lo_node->get_name( ).
  DATA(lf_value) = lo_node->get_value( ).

  "do something for text
  WRITE /: lf_name , lf_value.

  lo_node = lo_iterator->get_next( ).
ENDWHILE.
```

Comment: It is scary that there are still some people which do such things with coding instead of using XSLT.

Comment: @Jagger, what do you suggest ? call transformation?

Comment: @Jagger then prefer ST instead of XSLT (better performance)

Comment: What is ST ? could you please explain in detail to investigate.

Comment: @SandraRossi Wouldn't you have to change then the structure of the XML file, so that it meets the requirements for ST?

Comment: @Jagger, now I see your answer, I understand what you mean, I thought you were talking about defining each field statically.

Comment: @IvanDiazSalas I have edited your question yesterday so that it's a little bit more concise and more easy to reproduce. By the way, if the input XML is more or less static, you should better go for a "Simple Transformation" rather than iXML (and better go for ST rather than XSLT because of performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do in your code is transform. My hint is: do not write unnecessary coding for a thing that is already solved with XSLT.

Here is how you can do it in SAP. Go to transaction `STRANS` and create the following XSL transformation there. Let us name it `ZTEST`.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Totales">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /><xsl:text>
</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()" /><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text() | comment()" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Then just use `CALL TRANSFORMATION` to achieve what you want.

```
REPORT ZZZ.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA g_string TYPE string.
  DATA(g_ref_stream_factory) = cl_ixml=>create( )->create_stream_factory( ).
  DATA(g_ostream) = g_ref_stream_factory->create_ostream_cstring( g_string ).
  DATA(g_istream) =
    g_ref_stream_factory->create_istream_string(
      string =
                `<Body>                                      ` &&
                `  <Receptor>                                ` &&
                `    <RUTRecep>9655</RUTRecep>               ` &&
                `  </Receptor>                               ` &&
                `  <Totales>                                 ` &&
                `    <MntNeto>63934</MntNeto>                ` &&
                `    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>                   ` &&
                `    <MntTotal>76081</MntTotal>              ` &&
                `  </Totales>                                ` &&
                `</Body>                                     ` ).

  CALL TRANSFORMATION ZTEST
    SOURCE XML g_istream
    RESULT XML g_ostream.

  SPLIT g_string AT cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf INTO TABLE DATA(g_tab_string).
  LOOP AT g_tab_string ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<string_line>).
    WRITE / <string_line>.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: It is a simple transformation? if it yes, it is neccesary to create a internal table to save the data during CALL TRANSFORMATION ?

Comment: This is an XSL transformation. Let me check how to save the output as an internal table of string lines...

Comment: @IvanDiazSalas Here you have it. Maybe not the cleverest solution for splitting it into string table but this is what I could come up with in a short period of time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using a collection of nodes which correspond to all XML elements with the name `Totales`, so your collection contains only one node and the iterator will iterate one node only. The method `get_value` concatenates all texts of the node and its child nodes, at all depth levels.

Instead, don't use a collection, get the element with the name `Totales`, create an iterator on this node which will iterate on this node and its child nodes.

Moreover, nodes can be both elements and texts (and possibly other types like attributes, etc.) For `<name>value</name>`, there are two nodes, one of type element (name) and one of type text (value). This is useful to handle XML streams like for instance `<a>v1<b>v2</b>v3</a>`. So, to process only forms like `<name>value</name>`, you'll have to select nodes containing exactly one child being a text node.

```
DATA(lo_elem) = CAST if_ixml_node( lo_doc->find_from_path( path = '/Body/Totales' ) ).
IF lo_elem IS BOUND.
  DATA(lo_iterator) = lo_elem->create_iterator( ).

  DATA(lo_node) = lo_iterator->get_next( ). " get /Body/Totales node

  WHILE NOT lo_node IS INITIAL.
    " Only nodes of the form `<name>value</name>`
    IF lo_node->get_type( ) = lo_node->co_node_element
          AND lo_node->get_children( )->get_length( ) = 1
          AND lo_node->get_first_child( )->get_type( ) = lo_node->co_node_text.
      DATA(lf_name)  = lo_node->get_name( ).
      DATA(lf_value) = lo_node->get_value( ).

      "do something for text
      WRITE /: lf_name , lf_value.
    ENDIF.

    lo_node = lo_iterator->get_next( ).
  ENDWHILE.
ENDIF.
```

Result:

```
MntNeto
63934
TasaIVA
19
MntTotal
76081
```